# Change icon of table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, treetable

I want to change the icon of a table in jQuery but I am unable to find the element and change the background of it. I am working  with jQuery's treetable library.

This is my jQuery code:

```
Factory.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
        $rootScope.tree = data;
        console.log($rootScope.tree);
        buildTreeTable($rootScope.tree);
})


function buildTreeTable(tree){
    $("#example").treetable({
    expandable:     true,
    onNodeExpand:   nodeExpand,
    onNodeCollapse: nodeCollapse
});

function nodeExpand () {
    getNode(this.id);  
}


function nodeCollapse () {
    console.log("Collapsed: " + this.id);
}

$("#example tbody").on("mousedown", "tr", function() {
                                        $(".selected").not(this).removeClass("selected");
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});


var len = tree.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (tree[i].status == 1){
        var print = $('#example').attr('class').find('a').css("background-image","url(../../images/image.png)");
        console.log("Status is 1. Load icon for 1", print);
        }
}
```

And this is my html:

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <table id="example">
                <tbody>
                <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th >Tree data</th>
                        <th>Header1</th>
                        <th>Header2</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                </tbody>
                </table> 

                </div>
```

I want to change the icon of the `<td>` depending on what I get from my database, meaning if the status is 1, I load one background image, if the status is 2, I load another one.
My `<td>` element contains a `<span>` and `<a>` tag and I want to change the background image of `<a>` tag. How can I achieve that in `jQuery`?

This are my elements after the page is loaded:

[image]

This is the error that I get:

```
TypeError: $(...).attr(...).find is not a function
```

**EDIT:**

This code is how I am trying to load separate icons for each tr

```
function changeIcon(data){
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                if (data[i].status == 0){
                $('tr span.icon').each(function(){
                $(this).addClass('status');
        })
        console.log("Status is 0. Load icon for 0");
        }else if(data[i].status == 1){
        console.log("Status is 1. Load icon for 1");
        }else if(data[i].status == 2){
        console.log("Status is 2. Load icon for 2");
        }else
        console.log("Status is 3. Load icon for 3");

        }
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work. Explain what you want to do and what's happening so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I added already what I have tried. The problem is that the background image is not added to the <a> tag.

Comment: The data is loaded dynamically form the db.

Comment: There is no `<a>` tag in your HTML.

Comment: I added an image of my page after it is loaded.

Comment: Is this being loaded via AJAX or is this page rendered by something like PHP? You need to provide as much detail about your problem as you can.

Comment: Also, what errors, if any, are you getting in your javascript console?

Comment: I added the whole code from my controller.

Comment: Please clean up your code indenting. It's very hard to read like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because you have an unnecessary `.attr('class')` in your jQuery chain.

`.attr('name')` *returns* the value of an attribute with the name you supply to it. So what you're writing will return the value of the `class` attribute on the HTML element, it will not continue the jQuery chain. The `<table id="example">` has no `class` attribute, so the value returned will be `undefined`. You are then trying to run more jQuery methods on the chain like `.find()` but `undefined` isn't a jQuery object, you can't do that.

Change your line to:

```
 $('#example').find('a').css("background-image","url(../../images/image.png)");
```

The second problem is your for loop needs to be inside your `.then()` success handler function. Otherwise, it will get run immediately, rather than after the AJAX call finishes.

```
Factory.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
    $rootScope.tree = data;
    console.log($rootScope.tree);
    buildTreeTable($rootScope.tree);

    // put your background image code here
    $('#example').find('a').css("background-image","url(../../images/image.png)")
})
```

Third, you should read up on how jQuery selectors work because your selection is always going to find every `<a>` tag inside the entire table.

Comment: The background image is not applied to it. If I try to check if the a tag is found like this: var elem = $('#example').find('a').length;
console.log("Status is 1. Load icon for 1", elem); I get 0 in the console.

Comment: That's because it doesn't exist yet. See "the second problem"

Comment: Now, it cannot find the image. Why is that ? I get this error: GET http://localhost:8080/images/image.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You're using a relative path. Make sure the image exists two levels down in the URL, not the file system.

Comment: How is it possible to change the icon for a certain tr based on a value I get from the db ?

Comment: You need to use jquery's `.eq(index)`.

Comment: and what value should index have ? After I load my data I am able to see if one of the attributes contains 1, 2 or 3 and depending on this number I have to load an icon

Comment: but this value will not be loaded into the table

Comment: so how can I get to load separate icons based on my value from the db ?

Comment: @blaa this isn't a discussion forum. Ask a new question on StackOverflow specifically about how to do selectors and conditions within those selectors using JQuery.